# Debugger stopping at a non existent breakpoint in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, debugging, xcode4, breakpoints

Since upgrading to Xcode 4 my app stops at what I think are non existent break points. When it breaks there is no breakpoint showing in the breakpoint navigator and the editor says:

> Thread:1 Stopped at breakpoint 17

Anyone else seeing this? Is this something new, maybe?

Comment: For the record: Had the same problem. Restarted Xcode and this breakpoint (which, yeah, give, I had already, but I had removed it!) came back. Somehow it was not to be seen anymore but was still there...

Answer (score 26):

Maybe it's an Xcode bug but I still have a solution.

You can use LLDB to see and manipulate all the actual breakpoints.

Just type the following commands in the lldb window:

```
(lldb) is the prompt.

(lldb) help    -> for help
(lldb) help breakpoint   -> for breakpoint subcommand's help
(lldb) breakpoint list    -> list all the breakpoints.
(lldb) breakpoint delete  -> Delete the specified breakpoint(s).  If no breakpoints are
               specified, delete them all.
(lldb) breakpoint delete 7.1   -> delete breanpoint 7.1

and, you can use this command to continue the program:
(lldb) c
```

Comment: +1 because this actually lists the breakpoints with their numbers, which the breakpoint navigator does not. For me, it turns out that the exception breakpoint triggers, even though there is no exception thrown.

Comment: this problem is sometimes caused by deleting the codes points by a breakpoint. another way should try to solve the problem is in the breakpoint navigator select all the breakpoints then delete all.

Comment: another solution you can try: when debugger breaks on a unwanted position, you click the 6th icon on the left navigation panel, which means open break point navigator, you will see all break points there.  Let's say the current break position is at file A.cpp, so you click the first break point at the break point navigator, see if code editor show's at the position it has just stopped, if not, use down arrow key to navigate to next breakpoint, if yes, delete this break point at the navigator, then repeat down arrow key until you have checked all break points of A.cpp.

Comment: Opening the breakpoint navigator and deleting all breakpoints worked for me. (But the breakpoint navigator is now the seventh icon on the left navigation panel.)

Answer (score 4):

Press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to see all breakpoints.

Select the breakpoint that you want to remove and press <kbd>delete</kbd>.

Answer (score 4):

user278859's answer is basically really a true answer, as this seems to be a bug in Xcode 4. I just had the same problem. I set a breakpoint at one place in a `UIWebView delegate`'s `shoudlStartLoadWithRequest`-method (no other active breakpoints in the project) and the debugger stops in another method (in this case repeatedly `webViewDidFinishLoad:`) of the same object.

So I'd say this is an Xcode bug. Found no way of fixing this btw., other than removing the above breakpoint ... Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Your problem is a bit special, of course, because you set a breakpoint in code that never can be reached (because it is behind the "return YES;" at the top of the page). Most likely, XCode has not generated any code at all for that part, and therefore set the breakpoint at the nearest available code point, which is the webViewDidFinished method. Still a bug in XCode, for sure, but an understandable one.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I deleted the only breakpoint in the offending class which was no where near the line where the debugger was breaking and the problem went away.

Fasttracks, thanks for the suggestion. I am using xCode 4 and command+alt+b no longer works. There is now a Breakpoint Navigator where all the brekpoints are listed. There was no breakpoint in the list that corresponded to the line where the break was happening.

Comment: Please up-vote good answers and add a comment if you wish. Don't add an answer that, well, isn't an answer.

Comment: +1 Thanks this helped me. The breakpoint was in another class entirely and when removed the problem went away.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem before, I think its an Xcode bug. You may check if there any unwanted breakpoints created by Xcode in Breakpoint Navigator (cmd 6), delete them and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 4 introduced an Exception breakpoint which seems to be on by default.
i.e. when there's an exception it breaks.

This will catch an exception even if you haven't clicked the Breakpoints button.

You can check via the Debug Navigator whether it's been triggered - you'll see an "objc_exception_throw".

Answer (score 0):

Open the Breakpoints view: alt+shift+5 and then right click in the empty space and hit "delete all". It will actually remove the not existent breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

I found one additional case when such breakpoint is activated:

If you set breakpoint on the code, which is actually is not compiled for selected target this part of code is not highlighted or marked, and breakpoint is set actually elsewhere in this file where debugger consider is as close as it can.

So you need to be sure that code, where breakpoint is set is compiled :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing what exactly [Swift error breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34436629/how-to-edit-swift-error-breakpoint) is...I had enabled it by doing such:

[image]

Guess what happens?!

It will act like a breakpoint on errors thrown by your *own* code, i.e. wherever you use a `throw` statement.

For more see [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/xcode/what-are-swift-error-breakpoints) and [here](https://medium.com/@crafttang/intermediate-ios-debugging-3d7833f90c5f)