# How to edit swift error breakpoint?

Tags: swift, swift2, breakpoints

I want to set Swift error breakpoint to handle Swift Error of **ErrorType** in swift. But i am not getting What to set as Type value in BreakPoint ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_a_swift_error_breakpoint.html Check this. i think you do not have to define specific error type. It will halt execution for any swift error.

Comment: This will stop execution for any type of swift error, but i want to stop flow for particular type of error of swift.

Comment: I am not sure but as per I read through documentation, Swift error break-point will set without setting any specific error type.

Comment: I think you are looking for this https://realm.io/news/testing-swift-error-type/

Comment: I am looking for same but how to use it with BreakPoint?

Comment: i don't know how we can use it with breakpoint. in case if you are looking for debugging tips there is a url http://natashatherobot.com/swift-debugging/ you can have a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just create a Swift error breakpoint, it breaks on anything that conforms to ErrorType.

If you put something in Type, it'll only break when that type is thrown.

In the following:

```
enum MyError: ErrorType
{
    case AnError
}

enum MyOtherError: ErrorType
{
    case AnotherError
}

public func throwAnError()
{
    do
    {
        throw MyOtherError.AnotherError
    }
    catch
    {
        print("Caught 1")
    }

    do
    {
        throw MyError.AnError
    }
    catch
    {
        print("Caught 2")
    }
}
```

A break on Swift error will cause the debugger to stop on both `throw` lines. If you put `MyError` in the `type` field, the debugger will only stop on the second throw line.